# React Redux showing undefined when the website starts

Tags: reactjs, laravel, redux, axios

My react based website shows props as undefined when I start the website but once I refresh, the props appear and things run smoothly.
I tried changing lifecycle methods as well but did not work.

My Component has:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)    
    this.state = {
        metas:                 [],
        url:                   '',
        title:                 '',
        description:           '',
        keyword:               '',
        selectedMeta:          '',
        flashMessage:          null,
        newMeta:                ''
    }
}

componentWillMount(){
    this.props.fetchMeta()
    this.setState({
        metas:  this.props.metas
    })
}
const mapStateToProps = state =>({
metas:                      state.admin.metaR,
flashMessage:               state.flash.flashMessage,
newMeta:                    state.admin.newMeta,
updatedMeta:                state.admin.updatedMeta
```

})

export default connect( mapStateToProps, { fetchMeta, addMeta, updateMeta } )(AdminMeta)

My Action has:

```
export const fetchMeta = () => dispatch => {
axios.get('/api/v1/adminMeta')
    .then( res =>res.data )
    .then(metas =>
        dispatch({ type: FETCH_META, payload: metas })
    )
}
```

My Reducer has:

```
case FETCH_META:            return { ...state, metaR: action.payload.datax }
```

Comment: I would not recommend setting an initial state in componentWillMount(). If you want to apply initial values to state then do so in the constructor. If your component needs to execute functionality and apply changes to the state when it mounts, then I would recommend doing so in componentDidMount()

Comment: Tried with that too, but it still shows undefined.

Comment: Have you tried using console.logs to check the lifecycle of your component? It should look something like:

1. componentWillMount()

2. render()

3. componentDidMount() <-- state change causing a new call to render

4. render()

If you see more that 1 componentDidMount() then you have a problem. It seems that there is something fundamentally wrong with your code since props should never be undefined. Maybe try looking through the parent-component of this component and see why the props passed to this child are undefined